# Using a workbook as a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I have two variables `Temp` and `aw` that are both workbooks. I want to test if `aw` is empty, and if so, assign it to be the activeworkbook. I tried

```
if len(aw) = 0 then
 set aw = activeworkbook
```

but I kept getting an error.

```
Static aw As Workbook
Dim Temp As Workbook
Set Temp = ActiveWorkbook
If Temp = aw Then
GoTo Here
ElseIf Len(aw) = 0 Then
Set aw = ActiveWorkbook
Else
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
aw.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("K5:K7").Clear
Set aw = Temp
aw.Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If
Here:
aw.Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("K5").Select
Selection.Value = 15 * 60
```

Comment: Why is `aw` a static variable?

Comment: Better use nothing than 0.

Comment: aw is static because I'm wanting it to remember which workbook was active the last time the macro was run, and if that has changed (hence the `If Temp = aw` line), go back to that workbook and clear a cell. It's all part of a convoluted series of macros. @cheezsteak

Comment: [Avoiding using `ActiveWorkbook`, `Activesheet`, `Selection`, etc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179) It will  simplify your project greatly.

Comment: That's definitely going to be a helpful link when I get the time to make some of those recommended changes. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Len` function is used to determine the length of a string of characters. It doesn't accept Workbook objects as input. (Not clear what the "length" of a workbook would be anyway!)

What you want to do instead is test whether `aw` is Nothing:

```
If aw Is Nothing Then Set aw = ActiveWorkbook
```